# Unable to pass double value in a const constructor

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class Foo {
  const Foo.one(Radius radius);

  // Error: Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.
  const Foo.two(double radius) : this.one(const Radius.circular(radius));
}
```

In the `Foo.two` constructor, why can't I just pass `radius` which itself is a constant? What's wrong in it?

PS: I don't want to fix the error by removing `const` from the constructor.

Comment: @mmcdon20 That perfectly answers the question and this comment deserves to be an answer.

Comment: I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `const Radius.circular(radius)`, the value of `radius` is not guaranteed to be `const` since initializing `Foo` as `const` is optional.

When you call a `const` constructor all of the arguments are required to be `const` as well, but it can't be guaranteed in this case.

Some people have requested that dart should support some kind of feature like this ([github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2000](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2000), [github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823)), but it is not possible in dart currently.

An alternative would be to accept a `Radius` as an argument insted of `double`.